# Why is Terminal killing my command to switch to Miniforge?

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have an M1 Macbook, which is leading to some problems as I'm trying to use Tensorflow on Jupyter Notebook. I found that I have to use Miniforge as Anaconda does not support Tensorflow 2.2 on M1.

I tried multiple ways of downloading and installing Miniforge, including Homebrew, CI pipeline, and by downloading the shell files from https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge3.

If I go into my file explorer, I see that the "miniforge3" folder exists and was downloaded properly (seemingly). However, when I run this:
`{path}/miniforge3/condabin/conda init`
in Terminal, I am getting this response:
`zsh: killed {path}/miniforge3/condabin/conda init`.

A similar "killed" response occurs when I do the same process with bash instead of zsh.

I can tell that I am not getting what I need because when I run
`file $(which python)`,
it gives me `{path}/opt/anaconda3/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64` rather than what I expect it to, which is `{home path}/miniforge3/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`.

What can I do to fix this?

Or are there any alternatives that would allow me to run Tensorflow on Jupyter Notebook or JupyterLab on my M1?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved;

I had to go into the base .zshrc file and change all the paths with "anaconda3" to have "miniforge3" instead. This changed all the environment variables and I was able to run conda init.